# Why component in react dont re-rendering

Tags: reactjs

Hello why component in react was not rendering? State was updated and i see it in developer tools but content was not changing

FULL CODE: https://pastebin.com/bxNUAieV

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

const List = (props:any) => {
    const [actToDo, changeActTodo] = useState(props.actToDo)
    const [ToDoLists, changeActToDoLists] = useState(props.ToDoLists)
    return (
        <>
            {ToDoLists[actToDo].list.map((e:any, index:any) => (
            <div className={'Todo__element'}>
                <li key={index}>{e}</li><i className="fas fa-check"></i><i className="fas fa-recycle" onClick={() => props.removeElement(index)}></i>
            </div>))}
        </>
    )
}

export default List
```

ToDoLists[number].list save the list
actToDo save number

```
const removeElement = (index:any) => {
    console.log(index);
    let FullList = ToDoLists
    //@ts-ignore
    FullList[actToDo].list.splice(index,1)
    changeToDoLists(FullList)
    console.log(ToDoLists);
}
```

Comment: Can you show where you change the state? Your example never calls `changeActTodo`, nor `changeActToDoLists`.

Comment: try using a unique key whenever you're using array.map

Comment: i edit and add main component

Comment: You are not changing state properly. However, since the state is passed down in props, I don't see why you should store it change inside this component at all.

Comment: I add a pastebin link to full code

Comment: `useState(props.actToDo)` `useState(props.ToDoLists)` These only sets the initial value of the state. If the prop changes later, nothing will change in the child component. What's the reason that you're copying props into state?

Answer (score 1):

you are mutating the array, that will not work, also the `console.log` will display the wrong value as setState is async.

https://dev.to/il3ven/common-error-accidentally-mutating-state-in-react-4ndg

```
const removeElement = (index:any) => {
    console.log(index);
    let FullList = { 
       ...ToDoLists,
       [actToDo]: {
          ...ToDoLists[actToDo],
          list: ToDoLists[actToDo].list.splice(index,1)
       }
    }
    console.log(FullList);
    changeToDoLists(FullList);
}
```

by the way, saving props to state is a bad behavior, as if the prop change nothing will happen.

Answer (score 0):

What I can see in your code is that you are directly modifying a state variable, which we should never do in React. To modify a state variable first make its copy in a new variable, and after making changes , pass that new variable in setState function :

So instead of :

```
let FullList = ToDoLists
```

do like this :

```
let FullList = _.cloneDeep(objects);  //(using Lodash deep clone method here)
changeToDoLists(FullList);
```

Also , if you want to console your new list, then you should use useContext hook, since useState acts asynchronously and will not update value immediately, so console on very next line will not give updated value :

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('Here is my new list after updation', ToDoLists);
  }, [ToDoLists]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because, **you are directly trying to update the same state array.**

> React compares the previous state with the updated state to decide if the component needs to be re-rendered. Modifying the state directly will disturb this process.

---

**While updating:**

Since you are updating the data **inplace** **using splice** at the previous state's address *i.e. mutating the same array and the updating state*, and the state `TodoLists` is a complex object (nested array), so, React **cant track** the update and thus **not detecting** the state change.

**While creating new item**

This is not happening at the time of new item creation as you are not directly appending/ mutating the old state, therefore, the state got updating and *react detects* state change.

**For removing the items, you can do is**

```
const removeElement = (index) => {
    console.log(index);
    let FullList = [...ToDoLists]; //<-- create copy of the list
    //@ts-ignore
    FullList[actToDo].list = [...FullList[actToDo]].list.filter( //<-- filter the list by removing toBeRemoved Object
      (_, i) => i !== index
    );
    console.log(FullList[actToDo]); 
    changeToDoLists(FullList); //update the state
};
```

**`Note`: Whi;e updating a complex object, always keep in mind to use `...` operator, which creates a `shallow copy` of your object for updating. It works both for `array` and `object`.**